# Android main menu

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, main-activity

I am working on an android project, and have created a splashscreen that is functional. When the splash activity is done, it moves on to my main activity.
my question is, should my main menu of the app be created on the main activity?

I have been searching around for inspiration and tutorials on how to create a menu, but the results are always the same (options menu and slide in menus) is there another keyword i could use? the only thing that comes close it is dashboard but it is not that layout i am looking for. Perhaps something like this:

URL=http://s1183.photobucket.com/user/nicegirl_11/media/258076-qik-video-connect-main-menu_zps620a8bb5.jpg.html

Comment: It seems like you're looking for UI advice in general.  You're right -- searching for 'menu' won't turn up what you want.  For the screenshot in question, you could easily achieve the effect using buttons/views that perform some action when touched.  That said, the UI you've suggested doesn't really match modern Android UI guidelines.

Comment: Splash screens on Android are generally a terrible, awful idea. Don't use them.

Comment: @EricFarraro so the main menu should not be in the main_activity?

Comment: @NathanWalters hmm okay, any reason for that? so i can understand why it is not a good idea

Comment: @Sangelices You can totally put the UI suggested in your main activity if you want. My point though was that the UI you suggested in the screenshot is not a "good" UI by modern UI standards. For instance, I usually look to popular applications -- any of Google's apps, Twitter, Facebook, etc... -- for inspiration on how modern Android UI's look. These influential apps dictate what users expect. The UI you suggested is very different from most of the popular apps.

To be totally clear, the UI you want can easily be built out of basic Android widgets (TextView, Button, Linear/RelativeLayout)

Comment: @EricFarraro thanks alot for the answer and yes i have notest that most "moderen" apps use the dashboard menu style